# How to make imageView move smoothly?

Tags: java, android, image, android-animation, flappy-bird-clone

I am creating an Android Flappy Bird clone, but I don't know how to make a imageView move smoothly? Here is what I have done so far.

```
public void up(final ImageView i){


    CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(100, 100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            i.setY(i.getY() - 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            i.setY(i.getY() - 10);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Use View.animate( *property* ).  Or an ObjectAnimator.

Comment: As an aside, you should probably look into using canvas instead of actual views. The redraw overhead for what you want to accomplish is pretty extreme if you use just regular views.

Answer (score 0):

you can use animate() method to do the so

> setduration acc to your need..

```
public void up(final ImageView i){


CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(100, 100) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //i.setY(i.getY() - 10);
        i.animate().translationYBy(i.getY() - 10).setDuration(1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //i.setY(i.getY() - 10);
        i.animate().translationYBy(i.getY() - 10).setDuration(1000);
    }
}.start();
```

}